# how to convert PDF to BMP/PNG/JPG etc etc

Tags: delphi, pdf, imagemagick, delphi-7

I have a case here which I will need to convert PDF files to preferably PNG's at specified resolution.

I know imagemagick have some kind of conversion using convert.exe but this crashes for me everytime, I am using **Windows 7 x64**.

the prefered method to convert would be something integrated in the **delphi 7 components**, but I can also use commandline if that is what is needed to make this work.

My main concern is that I don't want this to just crash for people with a similar message
http://elhombre.members.winisp.net/vista_watson01.png

Comment: Our Delphi product PDFtoolkit has a RenderToStream function that can render PDF page contents to an image or a Tcanvas object. Recently, I wrote an article on [how to convert PDF to multipage TIFF images](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=194&t=Convert_PDF_Documents_to_Multipage_TIFF_Images_In_Delphi). TIFF is a bit complicated. If your requirements are just BMP or JPG, I promise you it is much more simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract from PDFs from Imagemagick you must have Ghostscript properly installed and a key set in the Windows Registry (`HKLM\Software\GPL Ghostscript`); on 64bit machines an additional `Wow6432Node` level stands inside this path.

Otherwise use `pdftoppm` from [xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/) and then use imagemagick to convert it to your raster format, if imagemagick fails. xpdf does not rely on delegates (like Ghostscript for PDF) for extracting from PDFs.

Comment: Sorry for an offtopic but do you happen to know a similar way to convert word documents to images?

Comment: @Kaitnieks: maybe with libgsf, from GNOME. No idea otherwise. You can use OLE2 automation to have Word make a PDF file and then you're back to the first problem.

Comment: ok, thanks. Since I need both pdfs and word docs, the 2nd way sounds great, if it's that easy :)

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check out [QuickPDF](http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/).  It's an all Delphi solution, is really easy to use, has an [enthusiastic user group](http://www.quickpdf.org/forum/), and an extensive manual of its hundreds of functions and is supported by Karl De Abrew whose name I have seen in PDF circles for lots of years.  With its [RenderPageToStream](http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/help/quickpdf/RenderPageToStream.php) function with options for output in 8 different graphic formats, I made my own PDF viewer in about an hour.

Comment: Very expensive for a regular user!