# Is it possible to display a PDF in a Report Builder report?

Tags: delphi, report, delphi-2010, reportbuilder

We use report builder to generate reports on our software developed with Delphi 2010. I have a lot of reports that display an image, but:

Is it possible to display a PDF in a report builder report just like we display a JPG?

One of our customers wants to display PDFs that contains only a single page with an image (dont ask me why he did not save it as JPG). But the problem is, he has a lot of pdfs that he does not want to convert.

Comment: I seriously doubt it since PDFs are multi-page. I have never seen anybody ever put a PDF into anything else in a Delphi reporting component.

Comment: Yeah, neither have I. But one of our customer wants to display PDFs that contains only a single page with an image (dont ask me why he did not save it as JPG). But the problem is, he has a lot of pdf that he does not want to convert.

Comment: Unless you call an inline previewer that grabs a screen dump and dumps a bitmap to disk and then puts that image in your report a solution, I doubt you'll find anything.  That would be one big image file, if it was a US LETTER or A4 size page at 600 dpi.

Comment: I doubt it to. I can also use tools to extract the image from the PDF, but that is a lot of work I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @RafaelColucci check this out http://wiki.freepascal.org/PascalMagick from what I understand you should be able to do a in memory conversion of PDF to image format of your choice with ImageMagick

Comment: gsdll32.dll (Ghostsript) may come to the rescue, please head [here](http://www.delphipraxis.net/165450-pdf-image-trim.html) (German page).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896333/how-to-convert-pdf-to-bmp-png-jpg-etc-etc

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to even try to embed a PDF in the report and is asking for trouble. He says he does not want to convert them - is this because the task would be tedious if done manually? You could propose that he uses a tool to automatically batch convert them to JPG (just do a search for free PDF batch conversion tools in your favorite search engine).

Comment: Why not place a link in the report to open the PDF on the appropriate viewer ? You can do that in the report.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible IF you convert the PDF to another image format.

refer to [how to convert PDF to BMP/PNG/JPG etc etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896333/how-to-convert-pdf-to-bmp-png-jpg-etc-etc)

or check out http://wiki.freepascal.org/PascalMagick